# Why is "Stand a chance of" considered an idiom?

Tags: idioms

According to Merriam-Webster, the phrase 'stand a chance of' is considered an idiom:

> **stand a chance of**
> idiom
>
> : to have a possibility of (succeeding or winning)
>
> - The team stands a chance of doing well this year.
> - I think she stands a good chance of winning the election.
>
> —often used in negative statements
>
> - She stands no chance of winning.

[Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand%20a%20chance%20of)

---

It seems to me, however, that "**stand a chance of**" is not an idiom because the "**stand**" in "**stand a chance of**" means just "*have*".

Why is "**stand a chance of**" considered to be an idiom?

Comment: Why do you think that "stand" normally means "have"? Both words have a lot of meanings so they may come close, but "stand a chance of" is a particular, fixed form of words that doesn't relate to the common senses of stand as a transitive verb (to endure, submit to, perform, pay, set upright). Often the meaning an idiom can be deducible by lateral thinking, while not being unambiguous or obvious.

Comment: What is your understanding of what an idiom is? Merriam-Webster defines it as *an expression in the usage of a language that is peculiar to itself either in having a meaning that cannot be derived from the conjoined meanings of its elements (such as up in the air for "undecided") or in its grammatically atypical use of words (such as give way)* None of the definitions of "stand" include "has". *I stand a book with a blue cover.* is gibberish.

Comment: I do not understand this type of question. The entire thing is in MW in black and white, labeled as an idiom, and clearly explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But *stand* **doesn't** mean "have" except in that idiom, and perhaps a few other expressions.